# Can we use information gathering questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I previously posted [a question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162957/what-lessons-can-be-learned-from-the-latest-spate-of-ransomware-attacks) about lessons that could be learned from recent cyber attacks, the question was very popular and garnered a good discussion on the issues and preventative measures used to stop them.

I know this is a technical help/guidance site, however when something so big happens having a page that talks about the issue will stop a lot of smaller queries and will also drive traffic to the site from people who are searching for answers.

I understand the question was broad however due to the amount of interaction on the question I would say it was a valid question/point to raise and was overall well received by the community and, isn't that what really matters, how well the community reacts to a post?

Look forward to seeing your feedback and thoughts.

Comment: [Wiki answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) seem to be more appropriate for such kind of post, but I saw them used only on exceptional basis (typically as a collective effort to write a canonical answer on a fundamental subject).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this is not a discussion site but a Q&A forum with a specific format. That format sets us apart, but yes, it also introduces limitations.

Take a look at the other highly-voted WannaCry posts to get a sense of how to handle important, highly searched topics when not all the data was known. Basically, ask a defined question and let the answers be undefined until they are.

Comment: The problem was, I wanted to know about WannaCry, Petya and NotPetya which is too broad, however I do understand your point about not being a discussion forum.